# How to prevent less --quit-if-one-screen --no-init +G from filling the screen with empty lines when the file is shorter than the screen?

Tags: less, pager

I use

```
less -XFR +G
```

to page some variations of `git log`, and **all four options are important**.

The thing I don't like is that it fills the screen with empty lines (marked with `~`) when the log/file is shorter than a screen.

The shorter repro steps that I could find are the following:

```
echo -e 'one\ntwo\nthree' | less -F +G
```

I would like the command to behave just like it was not there if the file fits the page.